# Dynamically change entity manager connection based on subdomain

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

I'm trying to change the db connection based on current subdomain.
So far I've managed to create a kernel.request listener and injecting the entity manager.

services.yaml

```yaml
services:
    app.listener.currentSubdomain:
        class: App\EventListener\CurrentSubdomainListener
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

CurrentSubdomainListener.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

class CurrentSubdomainListener{

  protected $entityManager;

  public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }

  public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event){
   
    //Change entity manager connection
  }
}
```

How can I set the entity manager connection inside onKernelRequest(), so that when I auto wire it into any controllers it'll automatically use the connection I set?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a multi-tenant situation and the connection information has to be retrieved from the db? Then it is kind of a catch 22, if you need database access to look it up, you cannot replace the service once it's been instantiated. You could create your own alias, but I'm not sure that would be problem-free, since I don't think the `ManagerRegistry` will be aware of this new manager.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do and why. Changing connection dynamically does not seem like a good idea to me. But, I think RequestEvent extends KernelEvent, which had getRequest() method, and Request has a getHost() method. This might be what you are looking for.